# How to get all commits in a Git tag through GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api, git-commit, git-tag

I have to fetch all new commits that were a part when a new tag was created on a Git repo. This needs to be done through GitHub API.

For example the Git UI says Tagging Tag1 and has a sha associated with it... let's say the sha is : SHA1

Now how do I get all commits which happened or were a part of Tag1 through GitHub API? I want to store all these commits and perform some analysis on them.

Comment: You will need to define what you mean. A tag name points to a single (one, 1) commit—but then, so does a branch name; but on the other hand, a branch name is *intended* to change over time, while a tag name is intended to point to just the 1 commit forever.

Comment: @torek : I meant "tag name which is intended to point to just the 1 commit forever", not a branch. I want to get all commits between this newly created tag and previous tag. All through GITHUB API. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I have no idea how to do this with the API. The biggest problem even *without* the API is defining "previous tag". Is v2.3.1 previous to v2.4.0? what if there is a v2.3.2 but it was created *after* v2.4.0?

Comment: Hi Akchay, I was wondering if the answer I provided has worked for you. If so, would you mind accepting it?

Comment: @rebagliatte:- Thanks for your answer, it works for me. Though I came across the /compare github api and already made use of it. But glad your advice is similar and appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the clarification on your comment:

> I want to get all commits between this newly created tag and previous tag

**1. Get all the tags in a given repo, so you can get the current and the previous tag names**

```
curl -X "GET" "https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/tags" \
     -H "Authorization: token YOUR_GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

[image: tags]

**2. Get all the commits between the latest 2 tags**

```
curl -X "GET" "https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/compare/:tag_1...:tag_2" \
     -H "Authorization: token YOUR_GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

[image]

Doc links:

- https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-tags
- https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits