# Get all commits before/in a tag for using Git cmd or GitHub API

Tags: git, api, github

We are building a deployment pipeline with integration with Github. We use a commit sha to figure out the code to deploy.

But before deploying, we want to make sure that commit sha indeed exists in a published release. To do that, I need to know all the commits (not just the commits between previous release and current release, but all commits) for that release.

With my research, I only found [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61359461/get-all-commits-in-a-git-tag-through-github-api-return-only-the-first-commit) for discovering commits between two releases.

Is there a way to get **all** commits for a release? So far the only way I can think of is use the above answer and do a recursive search to traverse all releases.

Another way to ask this question is, is there a way to get all commits before a specific commit in current branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ask only if a commit is in the history for a specific revision, then you can write this:

```
$ git merge-base --is-ancestor <historical-commit> <release-commit>
```

That will exit 0 (success) if the historical commit is an ancestor (in the history) of the release commit and 1 (failure) otherwise.

If all you want to know is whether a commit is reachable from *any* tag, you can use this:

```
$ git describe --contains <historical-revision>
```

That will exit 0 (and describe the revision) if it is an ancestor of a tag, and 128 if it is not.  You can use `--tags` to include lightweight (unannotated) tags, and use `--match` or `--exclude` to limit the tags being used.

If you want to add more revision options and restrict the list of commits more, then you'd need to write this:

```
$ git rev-list <release-commit> | grep -qsF <historical-commit>
```

That will exit similarly to `git merge-base`.

Note that you probably do not need `--first-parent` unless you are absolutely sure that you do not want to consider any commits merged from a side branch.  If you include that, you won't be able to query for commits that were merged in as part of a feature branch.

The GitHub API doesn't offer this functionality, and in general, walking history with the GitHub API is inefficient and slow since it isn't designed for that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the way using git:

```
git rev-list HEAD/<commit>/<release_tag> --first-parent
```

This will give you all the consolidated (--first-parent: no commits from a merging branch) commits before `HEAD` or `<commit>`.

Would still love to know the way to do it using GitHub API though.

FYI: The only API I found that should have this capability is https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits, but it does not have capability to show only commit and only first-parent, so the data would be huge.